Import JSON data null values to Database using python. Getting this error - data expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
I'm trying to import a JSON dataset to my PostgreSQL Database using python, but it throws error while trying to import null values.
Table's name is loan_info.
I tried this in python : -
for field in loan_info:
                            if loan_info[field] in ['Null', 'null', None]:
                                loan_info[field] = None

But it throws error - expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
Here's an example JSON dataset
{"results": [
        {
            
            "loan_info": {
                "loan_id": "",
                "loan_status": "",
                "loan_remarks": "",
                "loan_approved": "",
                "loan_offline_approved_on": "",
                "approved_loan_amount_inr": "",
                "disbursed_loan_amount_inr": "",
                "subvention_cost_percentage": "",
                "fldg_withhold_inr": "",
                "date_of_approval": "",
                "date_of_disbursement": "",
                "actual_program_fee": "",
                "scholarship_given": "",
                "scholarship_percentage": "",
                "is_remaining_fee_collected_offline": "",
                "remaining_fee_collected_offline_amount": "",
                "utr_details": ""
            },
             "loan_info": {
                "loan_id": null,
                "loan_status": null,
                "loan_remarks": null,
                "loan_approved": null,
                "loan_offline_approved_on": null,
                "approved_loan_amount_inr": null,
                "disbursed_loan_amount_inr": null,
                "subvention_cost_percentage": null,
                "fldg_withhold_inr": null,
                "date_of_approval": null,
                "date_of_disbursement": null,
                "actual_program_fee": null,
                "scholarship_given": null,
                "scholarship_percentage": null,
                "is_remaining_fee_collected_offline": null,
                "remaining_fee_collected_offline_amount": null,
                "utr_details": null
            }
}
]
}

Database Schema:-
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS loan_info (
    
    loan_id TEXT default null,
    loan_status TEXT default null,
    loan_remarks TEXT default null,
    loan_approved TEXT default null,
    loan_offline_approved_on DATE default null,
    approved_loan_amount_inr double precision default null,
    disbursed_loan_amount_inr double precision default null,
    subvention_cost_percentage double precision default null,
    fldg_withhold_inr double precision default null,
    date_of_approval DATE default null,
    date_of_disbursement DATE default null,
    actual_program_fee double precision default null,
    scholarship_given TEXT default null,
    scholarship_percentage double precision default null,
    is_remaining_fee_collected_offline TEXT default null,
    remaining_fee_collected_offline_amount double precision default null,
    utr_details TEXT default null
);

This is my python program.
import psycopg2
import json
from datetime import datetime
import re
import requests

# Database connection
def connect_db():
    return psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="Loan",
        user="abc",
        password="abc",
        host="localhost"
    )

# Format date
def format_date(date_str):
    if date_str and date_str.strip() != '':
        if date_str.strip() == '00/00/0000':
            return None
        try:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(date_str).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            except ValueError:
                return None
    return None

# Remove invisible characters
def remove_invisible_chars(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return re.sub(r'[\u200b-\u200d\uFEFF]', '', value).strip() or None
    return value

# Remove commas from numeric fields
def clean_numeric(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.replace(',', '')
    return value

# Check if a value is a valid number
def is_valid_number(value):
    return re.match(r'^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', value) is not None

# Prepare data for insertion
def prepare_data(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(f"Processing key: {key}, value: {value}")  # Debug statement
        value = remove_invisible_chars(value)
        value = clean_numeric(value)
        
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            data[key] = json.dumps(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            data[key] = json.dumps(value)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            if value == '':
                data[key] = None
            else:
                data[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            data[key] = value
        elif value is None or value in ['Null', 'null']:
            data[key] = None
        
        # Specific checks for empty strings to None for integer fields
        if key.endswith('_id') or key.endswith('_number') or key.endswith('_count'):
            try:
                data[key] = int(value) if value != '' else None
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                data[key] = None
        
        # Handle double precision and other numerical fields
        if key.endswith('_amount') or key.endswith('_percentage') or key.endswith('_score') or       key.endswith('_remaining_amount') or key == 'down_payment_remaining_fee':
            try:
                if is_valid_number(value):
                    data[key] = float(value)
                else:
                    data[key] = None
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                data[key] = None

        # Ensure date fields with empty strings are set to None
        if key.endswith('_date') or key.endswith('_on'):
            data[key] = format_date(value)



# Insert data into table
def insert_data(cur, table, data, page, record_index):
    if not data:
        return

    data = prepare_data(data)

    columns = data.keys()
    values = [data[column] for column in columns]
    print(f"Inserting into {table}: dict_keys({columns}) with values: {values}")  # Debug output
    
    for column, value in zip(columns, values):
        print(f"Column: {column}, Value: {value}, Type: {type(value)}")

    insert_statement = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({', '.join(columns)}) VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(columns))})"
    try:
        cur.execute(insert_statement, values)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error inserting data on page {page}, record {record_index}: {e}")
        for column, value in zip(columns, values):
            if value is None:
                print(f"Column {column} has value {value}")
        raise




def import_json_to_db(json_file_path, conn):
    with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for record in json_data['results']:
            
                loan_info = record.get('loan_info', {})
            
                for field in loan_info:
                    if loan_info[field] in ['Null', 'null', None]:
                                loan_info[field] = None
                        
                insert_data(cur, 'loan_info', loan_info, page, record_index)

def main():
    json_file_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\DataMigration\response40"

    try:
        conn = connect_db()
        conn.autocommit = False
        import_json_to_db(json_file_path, conn)
        conn.commit()
        print("Data imported successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        if conn:
            conn.rollback()
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

            


Please post the full traceback.

Aside: values = [data[column] for column in columns] can be simplified to values = list(data.values())

The JSON data doesn't have any 'Null' or 'null'. Are you sure you need to do that?
